# Can you run a SQL Server stored procedure using a login held in that procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, permissions

I have a stored procedure that requires the use of the `xp_dirtree` function.
This function currently only works when run by our SA account as it needs extra permissions to read a servers file system.

I am looking to get this to run off a VB.Net program but for obvious reasons I do not want to put the SA login details on the SQL Server connection string.
We have other use accounts that we use for accessing data from our programs.

My question: is there a way within the stored procedure code within SQL Server to execute this code something like:

```
Run AS: Login:'SA';Password:'xxxxxxx'
```

so that non-elevated accounts can execute the procedure, but it is then run under the elevated account?

Kind regards

Matt

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Execute As`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Demo  
    WITH EXECUTE AS 'SA'  
    AS  
    SELECT user_name(); -- Shows execution context is set to SA.  
    EXECUTE AS CALLER;  
    SELECT user_name(); -- Shows execution context is set to the caller of the module.  
    REVERT;  
    SELECT user_name(); -- Shows execution context is set to SA.  
GO
```

Comment: Hi Bastos. With this code sample it doesn't show anywhere a request for an SA account password. Does this mean that anyone that knows the SA username can then run scripts using that accounts permissions?

Comment: It means anyone invoking that SP, will invoke it under the permissions of the SA user. The calling user won’t even know that the SP is internally impersonating another user.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I'm going to have to look in to our permissions further as I tried running the code above as a test and now I get the message "Cannot execute as the user 'xxxxx', because it does not exist or you do not have permission." This is even though I am running the code logged in to the SA account, which does exists and should have all the permission needed.